# What zone should I believe about where I can grow sparkle berries?

Tags: berries

I've read on a plant catalog that sparkle berries are good to zone 5, but other places say it's good to zone 4, what should I believe?

Comment: Here's where I get the 4: http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/210/sparkleberry-winterberry/ but the plant catalog says 5.

Answer (score 3):

Listed as Zone 6 through to 9 by Floridata (see below) and I'd be more inclined to trust that as a source, especially if your conflicting information is from sellers of the plant

http://floridata.com/Plants/Ericaceae/Vaccinium%20arboreum/954

Comment: USDA says 5B: http://www.usna.usda.gov/Newintro/sparkle.html The question is more about how far north I could consider growing it.

Comment: Okay, some confusion here because you've used the name sparkleberry - I assumed you meant the edible vaccinum (blueberry), common name sparkleberry, but your link leads to Ilex (holly), variety name 'Sparkleberry',  which is not an edible berry. Which one are you actually asking about?

Comment: I was talking about: https://www.directgardening.com/4313-edibles/3072-sparkleberry#/quantity-1 and that was the one the USDA says can grow in 5 I believe.

Comment: Followed your link - that is not a good source of information, doesn't even give the botanical name of the plant they've pictured, so I've no idea, and wouldn't trust any site that didn't give botanical information/Latin name. One thing I do know though - the Ilex your other link leads to isn't the same plant at all because its certainly not edible.

Comment: I guess you could try contacting them and asking for  the Latin/botanical name, then you'd be able to check it elsewhere, somewhere more reliable.

Comment: which link has the poisonous berries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41352/discussion-between-black-thumb-and-bamboo).